# JSON_CONTAINS() in postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, laravel

Using MySQL 5.7, I want to know the PostgreSQL equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM user_conversations WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(users, JSON_ARRAY(1))
```

How do you write [`JSON_CONTAINS(users, JSON_ARRAY(1))`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) in PostgreSQL

**EDIT 1**

there is my json it's just an array without son object :

```
[
 "john", 
 "doe", 
 "does"
]
```

i want to get "doe" for exemple

**EDIT 2**

My table :

```
  Column   |              Type              |                     Modifiers                     | Storage | Statistics Target | Description 
 ------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-------------
  id         | uuid                           | non NULL                                                   | plain    |                       | 
  name       | character varying(255)         | non NULL                                              | extended |                       | 
  image      | character varying(255)         | non NULL Par défaut, 'default.png'::character varying | extended |                       | 
  users      | json                          | non NULL                                              | extended |                       | 
  type       | integer                        | non NULL                                              | plain    |                       | 
  emoji_id   | integer                        | non NULL Par défaut, 0                                | plain    |                       | 
  created_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                       | plain    |                       | 
  updated_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |
```

**EDIT 3:**
 I use laravel to execute queries :

```
DB::table('user_conversations')->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(users, JSON_ARRAY(1))')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

and it's work with mysql.

Comment: have you looked at the [library](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html). btw i have never used the mysql version nor this pgsql one. just thought that may be a good place to start

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string) may be your ticket as well

Comment: Can you paste the schema for `user_conversations`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll see my last edit

Answer (score 3):

The two argument form of MySQL's `JSON_CONTAINS()` you cite has a signature of [`JSON_CONTAINS(json_doc, val)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) That sounds similar to the [PostgreSQL JSON operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) operator

```
-- returns true
SELECT '["john","bob","doe","dylan","mike","does"]'::jsonb @>
  '["john","doe","does"]';

-- returns false
SELECT '["john","bob","doe","dylan","mike","does"]'::jsonb @>
  '["john","mary"]';
```

If your type is json, that's fine just cast it to `jsonb`;

```
SELECT *
FROM user_conversations
WHERE users::jsonb @> json_text;
```

Comment: i use json type not jsonb

Comment: @yecir you shouldn't, but it works the same, updated the answer.

Comment: but i want : select * from table where (json column)

Comment: I'm not sure, it's not clear what you're asking. JSON is a text column, validated. JSONB is a binary type that you can operate on. Text has to become binary to operate on it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM user_conversations WHERE users::jsonb @> "4411167c-4af8-39e8-b49a-85de76dc38cb";
ERROR:  column « 4411167c-4af8-39e8-b49a-85de76dc38cb » doesn't exists

Comment: ^ You need to use a single quote not double quotes

Comment: I love this! But can anyone help me with one problem? What if the search text isn't part of an array? 
`-- returns false because no array markers!`

`SELECT '["john","bob"]'::jsonb @>`

`' "john" '::jsonb;  -- NOTE: array markers [ and ] were removed.`