# Rails activerecord find parent given child model id, when parent has a field which is array of child ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

some help please. I have an Activerecord object called Estate. Inside Estate, there is a field which is an array of ids for another Activerecord object called House.
So it looks something like this; `Estate ... houses: [an_array_of_house_ids]` while `House id:value ...`. House is its own thing with **NO ASSOCIATION** to Estate. Now if I have an arbitrary `house_id`, how can I query activerecord to get the Estate in which this house belongs to or if it does not belong to any Estate in my database?

For example lets say the DB looks like this;

```
Estate
_____________________________________________
| estate_id   |    houses      |other_fileds|
---------------------------------------------
|       1     | [1, 2, 3, 4]   |      .     |
---------------------------------------------
|       2     | [5, 15, 3, 4] |      .     |
---------------------------------------------
|       3     | [6, 7, 8, 4] |      .     |
---------------------------------------------

# The houses fields has arrays of house_ids from the table below

House
_____________________________________________
| house_id    | other_fileds|
---------------------------------------------
|       1     |       .     |
---------------------------------------------
|       2     |       .     |
---------------------------------------------
|       3     |       .     |
---------------------------------------------
```

Given I have the house_id, let's say house_id=3, what would be the most optimal way to get the estate_id(s) for this house?

Comment: Do you have the option of changing the design? An array of ids seems like not the greatest idea.

Comment: No I don't have this option currently.

Comment: Which database and is `houses` a real array or some `serialize`d YAML mess?

Comment: It is a postgresql database and yes houses is serialized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string

Comment: If you're using `serialize :houses` then you're in for some pain, if the `houses` column is an `integer[]` then there are some [array functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Estate.where("?= ANY(houses)", house_id).ids
```

Note: where **house_id** can be your Search Criteria

Comment: Estate.where("?= ANY(houses)", house.id) worked for me. Thank you much Ketan Mangukiya.

Comment: This resource was also helpful [https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)

Answer (score 0):

In House class you specify `belongs_to` association with lambda like this

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
...
belongs_to :estate, ->(house) { Estate.where("?=ANY(houses)", house.id).first }
...
end
```