# Postgres get all elements where value matches from jsonb array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, where-clause

I think I am trying something simple, but after hours I just can't get it to work. I have a table which contains a tags column, which is a jsonb array and looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "e-commerce",
        "weight": 400
    },
    {
        "name": "management",
        "weight": 200
    },
    {
        "name": "content management",
        "weight": 200
    }
]
```

I now want to write a query which returns the full object to me, when the name matches the search string. So far I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE tags is not null
  AND EXISTS(
        SELECT FROM data ad WHERE (ad.tags -> 'name' ->> 'education')::text
    );
```

But I get this error:

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb[] -> unknown Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am not sure where I should do a typecast and whether that is really the problem.

I already tried solutions from [these](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/search-for-nested-values-in-jsonb-array-with-greater-operator) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string#27144175), but to no avail :-(

Comment: Is that really the content of your JSON column? Those escaped double quotes look wrong, it seems the value has been stored as a single scalar values, rather than a proper JSON object.

Comment: I am not the most familiar with arrays and objects in postgres. My colleague created the table, but when I query it, I get back an array of objects.

Comment: I just checked the database definition and it is indeed a jsonb:
`tags jsonb[] default'{}'::jsonb[]`

Comment: `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense. A "plain" `jsonb` that includes a real JSON array is  a much better choice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want each matching object on a separate row, you can use `jsonb_array_elements()` to unnest the array of objects, then filter:

```
select o.obj
from data d
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(d.tags) o(obj)
where o.obj ->> 'name' = 'education'
```

That works in you have JSONB array (so the datatype of data is `jsonb`).

If, on the other hand, you have an array of json objects (so: `jsonb[]`), you can `unnest` instead:

```
select o.obj
from data d
cross join lateral unnest(d.tags) o(obj)
where o.obj ->> 'name' = 'education'
```

Note that this generates two rows when two objects match in the same array. If you want just one row, you can use `exists` instead:

```
select o.obj
from data d
where exists (
    select 1 from unnest(d.tags) o(obj) where o.obj ->> 'name' = 'education'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to query the objects within the `json array`. Create those objects using `jsonb_array_elements` and then query the json like -

```
SELECT d.* FROM data d, jsonb_array_elements(d.tags) tag
WHERE tag is not null and  WHERE (tag -> 'name') ? 'education'
```

Also, a note, in your original query

This -

```
WHERE (ad.tags -> 'name' ->> 'education')::text
```

Should be -

```
WHERE (ad.tags -> 'name') ? 'education'
```

Or

```
WHERE (ad.tags ->> 'name')::text = 'education'
```

---

### EDIT 1:

Since your data type is not jsonb but jsonb[], you need to unnest it to jsonb using `unnest` -

```
SELECT * FROM data d, jsonb_array_elements(unnest(d.tags)) tagObj
WHERE tagObj is not null and  WHERE (tag -> 'name') ? 'education'
```

Or

```
select * from (
SELECT * FROM data d, jsonb_array_elements(unnest(d.tags)) tagobj
) a WHERE tag is not null and  WHERE (tag -> 'name') ? 'education'
```

First one may give error, due to `tagObj` not being available at that context

---

Comment: The second WHERE in your answer should be removed. Unfortunately, I get this error:
[42883] ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements(jsonb[]) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 32

Comment: @Gh05d, Yes, its because your data type is `jsonb[]` instead of `jsonb`, you need to unnest it into `jsonb`. I have updated the answer.