# Postgres - Query for nested value in nested array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

I have a table called `clients` with a column called `configs` containing JSON object.

```
{
    "pos_link": {
        "primary_id": "000123",
        "sub_ids": ["000123", "000124", "00125", "000126"],
       
    },
    "prime_tags": {
        "tags": ["Children"]
    }
}
```

How do I find all entries where one of the `sub_id` is '00124'

```
select *
from clients c,
jsonb_array_elements(c.configs->'pos_link') pos_link,
jsonb_array_elements(pos_link->'sub_ids') sub_ids
where sub_id IN ('00124')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a Postgres JSON array contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) `?`

```
select *
from clients
where configs -> 'pos_link' -> 'sub_ids' ? '000124';
```

This assumes that `configs` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `configs::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/mbAGh2Ds?hide=2)

Comment: very elegant and simple. Works perfectly!! Thank You !