# Use JSON array in SQL query in the repository

Tags: postgresql, jpql, quarkus-panache, json-arrayagg

In my PostgreSQL table I have a `parts` column of type `json`. I want to check if the given argument is contained in my json column.
This query works in the database:

```
select * from elements we
where parts::text like '%"CHEST"%'
```

However, it doesn't work in my repository, I'm not sure but it's probably jpql:

```
@Override
public List<ElementView> test() {
    return entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT w FROM ElementView w " +
                            "WHERE we.parts::text like '%CHEST%'", ElementView.class)
            .getResultList();
}
```

Is it possible to use this query (or another) to check the json array in the repository?

Comment: Another way to check whether a JSON column contains a string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27144175/20666497

Answer (score 0):

See if this example solves it :

```
SELECT * , a.json->'parts'
FROM (SELECT '{"parts":"CHEST"}'::JSON as json) AS a
WHERE  a.json->>'parts' = 'CHEST';
```

Notice there is two operators -> for selection and
->> for predicates.
They doesnt work when get their roles confused.

Answer (score 0):

The query "in your repository" can't work because the table alias is `w`, but you reference `we`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w FROM ElementView w
WHERE we.parts::text like '%CHEST%'
```

Also not sure about your upper-case letters in the search term `'%CHEST%'`. You might want:

```
... WHERE w."parts"::text ILIKE '%chest%'
```

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336665/lower-like-vs-ilike/20337500#20337500)

But this is hugely expensive and unspecific. Depending on what "contained" is supposed to mean exactly, and if your JSON column is actually **type `jsonb`** (much) more efficient queries with index support are possible. Like ...

*Does "CHEST" exist as top-level key or array element (not as value) within the jsonb column?*

```
... WHERE w."parts" ? 'CHEST'
```

See:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)