# Supabase RLS on app_meta_data

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have a supabase db with auth on which I use app_meta_data to store user role (as an array):

```
{
  "role": [
    "admin",
    "user"
  ],
  "provider": "email",
  "providers": [
    "email"
  ]
}
```

I have a table where I want to restrict access to rows where the user_id is the auth.uid() OR the user role contains admin.

I saw this link: [RLS Helper Functions](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#helper-functions)

```
(team_id in (select auth.jwt() -> 'app_metadata' -> 'teams'));
```

and tried to adapt it for my use case:

```
(auth.uid() = user_id or ( "admin" in (select auth.jwt() -> 'app_metadata' -> 'role')))
```

however it does not work. I am clearly not understanding properly.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it appears that I was close, but after some more work, I found the answer

The USING clause looks as follows:

```
((auth.uid() = user_id) OR (( SELECT ((auth.jwt() -> 'app_metadata'::text) -> 'role'::text)) ? 'admin'::text)
```

I was able to work this out courtesy of this SO Thread [Check if a Postgres JSON array contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925641/check-if-a-postgres-json-array-contains-a-string)

HTH